# (basic) For Next Loop: 1 To 9 Step 1 (list 9 lines of calculations increment up one multiplier each new line)

Tags: loops, for-loop, basic

I'm trying to display 9 lines of calculations and increment the multiplier each new line

```
    Dim dblInputNumber As Double
    Dim dblResult As Double

    Double.TryParse(txtInputNumber.Text, dblInputNumber)

    For intMultiples As Integer = 1 To 9 Step 1
        dblResult = dblInputNumber * intMultiples
        lblDisplayTable.Text = dblInputNumber & " " & "*" & " " & intMultiples & " " & "=" & " " & dblResult & ControlChars.NewLine
    Next intMultiples
```

It doesn't work, it only displays one line and doesn't repeat it. I want there to be 9 lines it only does one.

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question?

Comment: It doesn't work it only displays one line and doesn't repeat it. I want there to be 9 lines it only does one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not use if the control you used for lblDisplayTable support multiple lines, but try this:

```
    lblDisplayTable.Text = lblDisplayTable.Text + dblInputNumber & " " & "*" & " " & intMultiples & " " & "=" & " " & dblResult & ControlChars.NewLine
```